# AngularJS: convert bound value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bound list and I'm looking for a way to "convert" the variable that it's bound to i.e. in the example below I want to bind the backgroundColor to int variable but using some functionality where I could change the color based using some predefined logic (red for state=0, blue for state=1, and black for state=2).

http://jsfiddle.net/UWqWf/16/

I could do this via dom manupulation in the click event but i would have to write "dirty" code to change the color and also make sure to update the $scope.items[x]

Can this be done?

```
<ul ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="toggle()"> <span style="background-color: {{i.state}}"> {{i.name}} </span> </li>
</ul>



function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{"name":"a","state":"1"},{"name":"b","state":"2"}, {"name":"c","state":"0"}];
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        // toggle the state i.e.
        // if state<3 then state++
        // else state=0 
     };
};
```

Comment: your fiddle is broken.  Try replacing the `=` with `:` in the array and you don't have to encapsulate the property names with `"`.  Then add angular support to the fiddle.

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnson agree, your items are not valid json objects

Comment: thanks didnt realized that it was broken. I was going for the concepts anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to keep my styles out of javascript

```
<style>
.state-0{ background-color: red;}
.state-1{ background-color: blue;}
.state-2{ background-color: black;}
</style>

<ul ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="toggle()"> 
    <span class="state-{{i.state}}">
      {{i.name}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The preferred way of angular is to apply styles by adding or removing classes. ng-animate is a big example of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try something like this? You don't need to perform DOM manipulation yourself. You could instead pass in the the item of that iteration in the `toggle` method itself.

```
<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="toggle(i)"> 
        <span style="background-color: {{getColor(i.state)}}"> {{i.name}} </span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{"name":"Item1","state":1},{"name":"Item2","state":2}, {"name":"Item3","state":0}];
    $scope.color = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    $scope.getColor = function(state){
        return $scope.color[state];
    }

    $scope.toggle = function(item){
          if (item.state<3 )
             item.state++;
         else 
             item.state=0 ;
     };
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x3tzn/)**

Or just simple get rid of the method `getColor`

```
 <span style="background-color: {{color[i.state]}}"> {{i.name}} </span>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NYusB/)**

Comment: amazing, didnt realize that it couldnt be this simple!

Comment: the click event calls toggle() that changes the state and passes in the item from the repeater